# Entity with one to many self reference save all cascade issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save list of MyClass. It has many-to-one self reference, and when I try to save list with cascade persist, the parent class is being added multiple times, with each of its children, rather than only once.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class MyClass{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "automotiveparts_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "automotiveparts_sequence",
            sequenceName = "automotiveparts_sequence",
            allocationSize = 50
    )
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myclass_parent_id")
    private MyClassparent;

}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyClassService {

    private final MyClassRepository myClassRepository;
    private final MyClassMapper myClass1Mapper;

    @Transactional
   public void importProcess(List<MyClass1Dto> imports) {
 
        myClassRepository.saveAll(imports.stream()
                .map(m -> {
                    MyClass myClass= mapDtoToEntity(m);
                    return myClass;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

I think it happens because I am creating the parent object a couple of times, but I can't think of pretty way of doing that.

Comment: Your comment points to the issue. You have to think of hibernate/JPA as a "mapper" of what you have in the DB. If you are creating multiple _parent_ objects, they will be stored as different rows. To solve this create the parent once and reuse the same object instance.

Comment: Please show `MyClassparent` and `mapDtoToEntity()` code.